# TYPO3 tx_form doesn't render submit button

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

I have a 10.4.18 installation, on another project that works fine (which i copy to the current). In my current project they render the submit button like this:

```
<span class="btn-group next submit">
   Absenden
</span>
```

There is no button and not clickable, anyone have an idea? There are no template overrides or custom configuration, form is added in template (without I get an exception) so that works.

The yaml configuration:

```
renderingOptions:
  submitButtonLabel: Absenden
identifier: kontakt
label: Kontakt
type: Form
prototypeName: standard
finishers:
  -
    options:
      subject: 'Kontakt über Website'
      recipients:
        test@test.de: 'Test Webmailer'
      senderAddress: '{email}'
      senderName: '{vorname}'
      attachUploads: true
      translation:
        language: default
      useFluidEmail: true
      title: 'Confirmation of your message'
      addHtmlPart: true
    identifier: EmailToReceiver
renderables:
  -
    renderingOptions:
      previousButtonLabel: ''
      nextButtonLabel: ''
    identifier: page-1
    label: Kontakt
    type: Page
    renderables:
      -
        properties:
          options:
            Anfrage: Anfrage
            Lob: Lob
            Kritik: Kritik
        type: SingleSelect
        identifier: singleselect-1
        label: 'Ihr Anliegen'
        defaultValue: Anfrage
      -
        defaultValue: ''
        identifier: vorname
        label: 'Ihr Name'
        type: Text
        properties:
          fluidAdditionalAttributes: {  }
          elementDescription: ''
      -
        defaultValue: ''
        identifier: email
        label: 'Ihre E-Mail-Adresse'
        type: Text
        properties:
          fluidAdditionalAttributes:
            required: required
        validators:
          -
            identifier: NotEmpty
          -
            identifier: EmailAddress
      -
        defaultValue: ''
        identifier: nachricht
        label: 'Ihre Nachricht'
        type: Textarea
        properties:
          fluidAdditionalAttributes:
            required: required
          elementDescription: ''
        validators:
          -
            identifier: NotEmpty
      -
        properties:
          pageUid: '13'
          linkText: 'Datenschutzerklärung anzeigen'
          fluidAdditionalAttributes:
            required: required
        type: LinkedCheckbox
        identifier: linkedcheckbox-1
        label: 'Ja, ich habe die Datenschutzerklärung zur Kenntnis genommen.'
        validators:
          -
            identifier: NotEmpty
```

Comment: How is the form added to the template? And which exception do you get when you use the Form plugin?

Comment: the form is added via template includes as last position. if i remove it from template i get an exception, with not. so the form is added correctly

Comment: So I misunderstood you. You added the static TypoScript via template includes and are showing the form via the form plugin. You might want to post the form .yaml definition.

Comment: i add the yaml to my post

Comment: I tested your .yaml in 10.4.20 and it works for me. The resulting HTML for the submit button is: `<span class="btn-group next submit"><button class="btn btn-primary" name="tx_form_formframework[kontakt-53329][__currentPage]" type="submit" value="1"> Absenden </button></span>`
There were known problems with the HTML output in 10.4.19 due to a security patch but 10.4.18 shouldn't be affected. In any case, you might want to try 10.4.20.